# Equilibrium between spring and centrifugal force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, spring, rotational-kinematics

I was doing a problem regarding balancing springs in rotation about an axis with a respective centrifugal force.

[image]

Axis of rotation goes through a human. Springs starts 1 meter away from the axis of rotation and the spring equilibrium length is 1 meter. There is a mass at the end of the spring.

When stretched (due to rotation), it will measure 2L + x, where L = 1 and x = the stretched distance.

Given K = 100N/m

m = 1kg

L = 1 meter

Tension spring = centrifugal force

$$\begin{align}100x&=m\omega^2(2+x)\\ 100x-m\omega^2x&=2m\omega^2\\ x(100-m\omega^2)&=2m\omega^2\\ &\to m=1\ \mathrm{kg}\\ x(100-\omega^2)&=2\omega^2\\ x&=\frac{2\omega^2}{100-\omega^2}\end{align}$$

## **A solution which breaks at ω=10.**

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Or why does that happen?

Thanks for any insights you may provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct for $|\omega| < 10$. When $\omega=10$ the spring exerts an inwards force of $100x$ N on the mass at extension $x$ metres, but the centripetal force required to keep the mass moving in a circle with radius $2+x$ metres is $200 + 100x$ N, which is always greater than $100x$ N. So when $\omega=10$ the spring is not strong enough to keep the mass moving in a circle, no matter how far it is extended.